# How to fix makefile error in"6LoWPAN Simulation Model Integrate It Yourself Manual"?

Tags: omnet++, 6lowpan

I work on 6lowpan in omnet++ (Michael Kirsche), but after integrating I have makefile error.
some details:
Omnet-4.6
Inetmanet2.2 (Michael Kirsche)

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu16/inetmanet-2.0/src'
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

can you please help me to fix this error?

Thank you

according to instructions of the 6LoWPAN Simulation Model Integrate It Yourself Manual I set my network. But in the last step when I ran "make makefiles" I got an error.

Comment: The error message gives zero information about the cause, so no one will be able to help you. It just says: There is an error. The lines before the final error message are important as they might give a hint about the actual cause.